# Jquery does not work when apache server is turn off

Tags: jquery, apache

Well, what the title says.

Its quite weird. If I try to access an html file with apache server turned off or making "double click" on it, It just does not work, I dont know why.

I thougth jquery did not need a server to run. I mean, its just JS, isnt it?

Could it be that I am using the google code one instead of a local version?

Comment: What do you mean, "does not work"?

Comment: Just that it does not work, it does not load on the page.

Comment: Does your link to the Google Code start with `http://`, or just `//`?

Comment: just //

Note: I have tried including a local version of jquery and I works, i mean, the script does what it should do

Comment: Mooseman, i have changed the // for http:// and it work :D
Please put your comment as an answer so I can choose it and vote it :D

Thanks :D